# How to read the values logged from built in iterables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm digging into Iterables and Iterators in JavaScript and wanted to understand how to read the value returned from Symbol.iterator for the built in iterables

```
const str = new String()
const arr = new Array()
const map = new Map()
const set = new Set()

console.log(str[Symbol.iterator]()) Returns Object [String Iterator] {}
console.log(arr[Symbol.iterator]()) Returns Object [Array Iterator] {}
console.log(map[Symbol.iterator]()) Returns [Map Entries] {  }
console.log(set[Symbol.iterator]()) Returns [Set Iterator] {  }
```

Would someone be able to translate the return value in each of the above cases to simple english readable format please? Thanks in advance

Comment: What "value" do you expect to get? The iterator is an iterator, it doesn't have a value.

Comment: How would I explain to someone what is logged in the console is my question I guess. I understand it returns an iterator but as you can see all four have different iterators, how do I put them in simple English?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the same for each: you're getting an iterator back, which you can then use to step through the values contained in the string/object.

```
let str = 'Foobar'; //no need for a "constructed" string - a literal is fine
let it = str[Symbol.iterator]();
it.next().value; //"F"
it.next().value; //"o", etc
```

Or for the array:

```
let arr = [5, 7, 9];
let it = arr[Symbol.iterator]();
it.next().value; //5
```

---- EDIT ----

In answer to your comment, it is an iterator object. There is no explicit difference between an iterator object belonging to a string versus one belonging to a map - there are just iterables (to which all four of your examples belong) and iterators.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that it returns an iterator. If I were to explain what is "Object [String Iterator] {}" to someone in english, what would I tell? Its an object and in particular a string iterator? If it is so, is Map entries an iterator? I'm looking for plain english translation of the return type I guess.